# ServiceStack service for none standard rest + overall confusion

Tags: servicestack

I would really like to utilize servicestack for a service I need to write but I'm hitting a mental block wrapping my mind around how it works, and more precisely how I can make it work for my intents and purposes. I don't have a strong asp background, mainly backend, so maybe that's why the mental block.

I have a legacy platform to which I connect via native c++ api. I have warped the native api in cli as a .net class library, this would be my equivalent of the Todo repo being injected in the samples.

The data moving back and forth is exposed in the class lib as value structs. For example account would be defined like this:

```
struct Account{
  int id;
  string name;
  string password;
  ...
}
```

Order would be something like this:

```
struct Order{
  int orderId;
  int account;
  string comment;
  ...
}
```

The lib exposes a lot of functionality and operations for all sorts of different objects defined similarly to the above. What i'm trying to understand is this:

1) How do I register the api with the container? More precisely, I don't understand how the Register method knows what type its supposed to get. In the todo sample everything is defined in the same assembly so its hard to see how the backend gets injected.

2) Is there a way to manage the lifecylce of the back end in the framework. Can I make it a singleton across all connections.

3) Do I have to wrap my structs in classes that map fields to a request. Not quiet clear on how the request objects are defined, it seems that the content of the request should be fields that would translate to urls of fieldname/type for operations. If there is a way to not have to wrap, how do I then limit which fields to expose in the api and which not to.

4)Do I absolutely have to create a service per data type, so in the structures above would I have to implement one service for Orders and one for Accounts of is there a way to combine them into one. I love that ss can be converted to talk over mq's, would making a combined service make it difficult to operate over mq's in the future, what are the cons to this approach.

5) Lastly, I would like to expose operations in the api that, afaik would violate the rest contract. Something like: archive accounts older then.... This would be an operation that returns success/fail status no update/delete ect. Essentially, drive some functionality via an http request. Is this possible in ss, if so, does using it in this way have any debilitating consequences to the framework's operation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To register your API you will want to use the built in IoC with Funq.

```
container.Register(c => new LegacyApiService())
       .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Container);
```

Funq is able to automatically wire these Services in your API Services. Take a look at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container.

You can also resolve anywhere container is available using the TryResolve method.

2) You can controls the Object lifetime with Funq by specifing ReuseScopes when you register them. You will want to look at

```
ReuseScope.Container: Singleton scope 
// a instance is used per application lifetime
```

3) You are going to need to create plan old classes (DTOs) for your structs. This is necessary for ServiceStack. All your DTOs public properties will get serialized. You can also optionally use DataMemberAttribute and the IgnoreDataMemberAttribute to control what public properties get serialized.

4) You will need to have a sservice per request DTO. However, you can keep this code at a minimun and call a centralized business layer. This is necessary since each route + verb needs to have a distinct operation, hence the one service class per DTO.

5) You can easily define more routes and there is nothing that forces you to adhere to REST rules, you are free to implement the HTTP verbs as you see fit. You can easily create specialized routes on GETs that perform an action such as archiving. There are no debilitating consequences here, just perhaps confusion to your API consumers. Just be sure everyone is clear how the API works with documentation.